# Align an enumerated list with matrices

Tags: amsmath, enumerate, matrices

I want to align the four matrices by the **item** label as in the following image.

[image]
 Any help in getting this done is much appreciated.

```
\documentclass[12 pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{multicol}

\begin{document}

\textbf{Example} : Find the transpose of each matrix.
\begin{multicols}{4}
\begin{enumerate}[(a)]
\item $\displaystyle{A=\begin{bmatrix}
2   \\
8   \\
\end{bmatrix}}$

\item $\displaystyle{B=\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 2 & 3  \\
4 & 5 & 6 \\
7 & 8 & 9  
\end{bmatrix}}$


\item $\displaystyle{C=\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 2 & 0  \\
2 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1  
\end{bmatrix}}$


\item $\displaystyle{D=\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 1  \\
2 & 4  \\
1 & -1  
\end{bmatrix}}$
\end{enumerate}
\end{multicols}


\end{document}
```

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by "I want to align the four matrices by the item label". Horizontal alignment? Vertical alignment? Something else?

Comment: @Mico, I expect that to be as in the image. What I have right now is except (a), rest of the items appear below (a).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use an inline `enumerate*` environment from `enumitem`, instead of using a `multicol` environment.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[inline]{enumitem}

\begin{document}

\textbf{Example} : Find the transpose of each matrix.

\begin{enumerate*}[label=\textbf{\alph*.}, itemjoin=\quad]
\item \(\displaystyle A=\begin{bmatrix}
2   \\
8   \\
\end{bmatrix}\)

\item \(\displaystyle B=\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 2 & 3  \\
4 & 5 & 6 \\
7 & 8 & 9  
\end{bmatrix}\)

\item \(\displaystyle C=\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 2 & 0  \\
2 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1  
\end{bmatrix}\)

\item \(\displaystyle D=\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 1  \\
2 & 4  \\
1 & -1  
\end{bmatrix}\)
\end{enumerate*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Is there anyway to get this work with the "enumerate" package ? Also, if at some other place in the document, I need an enumerated list which is not inline, this won't work either.

Comment: I don't think ``enumitem`` works with the ``enumerate`` package, but ``enumitem`` should provide all functionalities of ``enumerate``: see the [documentation](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/enumitem) of ``enumitem`` for more details. If you need an enumerated list which is not inline in the same document, it should work without problem using the standard (not starred) version of the ``enumerate`` environment.

Comment: Thank you. One last question, could you please tell me, instead of all 4 items on the same line, how to get two items on the top  line and two items on the bottom line.

Comment: @Quantas You could force a line break after an item, or you could use two separate ``enumerate*`` environment, using the ``resume`` option in the second one. The documentation of ``enumitem`` might have other (better) solutions, I'd suggest you search there also.